# trying to use onduplicate key with mysql

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, lucee

I have this code

```
<cfquery >
        INSERT IGNORE INTO tblcustomers(CustomerCode,CustomerID,FirstName,LastName,lid,status) 
        VALUES(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" value="#queryData.CustomerCode[currentRow]#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="integer" value="#queryData.customerID[currentRow]#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" value="#queryData.firstname[currentRow]#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" value="#queryData.lastname[currentRow]#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="integer" value="#queryData.LocationID[currentRow]#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="integer" value="#queryData.status[currentRow]#">
            )
        </cfquery>
```

trying to check if the customerID exists, it should do update, because customerID is unique

any clue how can i do it

Comment: I believe mySql has an `upsert` command.  I could check on Google, but then again, so can you.

Comment: first time heard about upsert but i believe its for mysql 8.0.0., i am on mysql 5.1

Answer (score 2):

you need to tell the database what to do if the record is already on file.

```
INSERT INTO tblcustomers(CustomerCode,CustomerID,FirstName,LastName,lid,status) 
VALUES
(
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" value="#queryData.CustomerCode[currentRow]#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="integer" value="#queryData.customerID[currentRow]#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" value="#queryData.firstname[currentRow]#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" value="#queryData.lastname[currentRow]#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="integer" value="#queryData.LocationID[currentRow]#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="integer" value="#queryData.status[currentRow]#">
)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
CustomerCode = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" value="#queryData.CustomerCode[currentRow]#">,
CustomerID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="integer" value="#queryData.customerID[currentRow]#">,
FirstName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" value="#queryData.firstname[currentRow]#">,
LastName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="varchar" value="#queryData.lastname[currentRow]#">,
lid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="integer" value="#queryData.LocationID[currentRow]#">,
status = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="integer" value="#queryData.status[currentRow]#">
```